# String comparison with alternate character variables

Tags: php, regex, string, comparison, preg-match

Right to the problem...user need to input text (to be specific the input text is serial number), this input must be compared with database. However because of small print user will make mistake between characters like: (B/8), (1/l),(0,o),(u,v).

The question is how to make the user input "l234B" a valid entry when the serial number is "12348"??

here is another examples: o12u3 ---> 012v3

thanks.

Comment: This is why serial numbers should not contain ambiguous characters. Better avoid introducing the problem in the first place by restricting the set of characters that a serial number is constructed from.

And of course, don't print serial numbers unreadably small (at least use a font where those characters are easily distinguishable).

Comment: Perhaps the non-obvious, but easier answer is to make the print bigger.

Comment: I doubt he's in charge of generating or printing them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some solution might be to replace all occorences like "8" by "[8B]" to match against both possibilities:

```
$sn = "l234B"; $sn_new = "";
$problematic_chars = ['B' => 'B8', '8' => 'B8', '1' => '1l', 'l' => '1l', ...];

// Go through original string and create new string
// "l234B" becomes "[1l]234[8B]"
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($sn); $i++) {
    $char = $sn[$i];
    if (array_key_exists($char, $problematic_chars)) {
      $sn_new .= "[".$problematic_chars[$char]."]";
    } else {
      $sn_new .= $char;
    }
}

// Query stuff
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE sn REGEXP '^${sn_new}\$'";
```

Did not write PHP for long time, but I think you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [similar_text](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) function rather than using regular expressions and validate only non-ambiguous chars.

Comment: Thank you, this is good but serial number can belong to a wrong product and still shows acceptable percentage of similarity.

Answer (score 0):

```
// to query
$id = "ABF8...";

// all combinations pre-generated
$c = array(
  array('B' => 'B', '8' => '8', ...),
  array('B' => 'B', '8' => 'B', ...),
  array('B' => '8', '8' => '8', ...),
  array('B' => '8', '8' => 'B', ...),
  ...
);

// generating all versions
foreach($c as $v)
{
  $ids[] = strtr($id, $v);
}
```

the optimal solution depends on your specific setup. but probably you will have the IDs somewhere and you have to query them. so you will have to replace the ambigiuous chars in all possible combinations and query those.

[strtr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php)